# How to respond to MvxLinearLayout's template item button click

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I have the following linear layout

```
            <MvxLinearLayout
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/add_skill"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:divider="?android:dividerHorizontal"
                local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Skills"
                local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemnameddelete" />
```

ItemNamedDelete.axml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MvxLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
android:dividerPadding="8dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Text"
    local:MvxBind="Text ." />
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
```

How do I specify what happens when the user clicks on the ImageButton?  I want this reusable so I was hoping I could specify the click binding from the MvxLinearLayout.  I tried "Click MyCommand" but that fires when I tap on the TextView.  ItemClick didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

What I know what you can do, is to declare an id in the layout-XML-file by `android:id="@+id/YourID"` and use this as a reference for attaching the onClick() event.

Here is a more detailed example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MvxLinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:showDividers="middle"
android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
android:dividerPadding="8dp">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Text"
    local:MvxBind="Text ." />
<ImageButton
    andorid:id="@+id/YourImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />
```

and use the findViewById function in the onCreated method of the related java activityClass.

```
findViewById(R.id.YourImageButton).setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        //Here goes your code ...
                    }
                });
```

Instead an anonymous instance of a class you can something reuseable. the relationship then is the id you defined.

**Update**

Of course ervery Item get an another Id so your linear layout has an Id, your image button, your TextView a.s.o. ...

Comment: But how does that work when another item is added to the linear layout?